# How can I upload the Cvisualize extension to my Civicrm?

Tags: extension

Good morning,

I'm new to Civicrm and I'm hooked!
I'm trying to upload an extension ( cvisualize) for all the reports and I don't know how to do it.
I go to the extensions menu and in "Add New" I get a list that does not include Cvisualize.
I have downloaded the .zip from the civi website, but I don't know how to upload it.
I work with woocomerce.
Can someone help me?

Greetings to the community, you are awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be in the Add New list, but note that list is unordered - try CTRL-F to find it in the page.

But if you want to do it manually, you can unzip it into the wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext folder.

More information: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/customize/extensions/#installing-a-new-extension

Comment: really thanks     I will try it!